# Estimating risk ratio instead of odds ratio in mixed effect logistic regression in `R`

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, odds-ratio, relative-risk

`glmer` is used to estimate effects on the logit scale of `y` when the data are clustered. In the following model

```
fit1 = glmer(y ~ treat + x + ( 1 | cluster), 
             family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

the `exp` of the coefficient of `treat` is the odds ratio of a binary `0-1` treatment variable, `x` is a covariate, and `cluster` is a clustering indicator across which we model a random effect (intercept). A standard approach in `glm`'s to estimate risk ratios is to use a `log` link instead, i.e. `family=binomial(link = "log")`. However using this in `glmer` I get error

```
Error in (function (fr, X, reTrms, family, nAGQ = 1L, 
 verbose = 0L, maxit = 100L,  : 
  (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in 
  pwrssUpdate
```

after calling

```
fit1 = glmer(y ~ treat + x + ( 1 | cluster), 
             family = binomial(link = "log"))
```

A web search revealed other people had similar issues with the `Gamma` family.

I am not sure if this is due to my data or a general problem. My question thus is: how can I estimate risk ratios using a mixed effect model like `glmer`, preferably in `R`?

I saw that `stata` has a function `meglm` which seems to allow this link and family. Not sure if this works there.

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to use a log link, since that will not constrain the response properly. Have you tried other packages such as `brms` and GLMMAdaptive` ?

Comment: @RobertLong Thanks, I am also not absolutely sure. My idea was that I have to use the log link as I thought this is the general way it's done in `glm`. Maybe I am wrong? I cannot use Bayesian statistics for this analysis. GLMMAdaptive may be an option, I will check. So my general question is indeed how to do it rather than what's the cause of this specific error.

Comment: I would recommend that you stick with the odds ratio that is a natural output from logistic regression.

Comment: Here is an example, but without random effects  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/289008/confidence-interval-on-binomial-effect-size/406746#406746

Comment: Estimate a marginal effect

Comment: Changing from a probably well-fitting link function to a surely poorly-fitting one is dubious.  Use the logistic model to get covariate-specific risk ratios as shown [here](https://www.fharrell.com/post/varyor).  Unlike odds ratios, risk ratios are incapable of being constant over a wide range of baseline risk.  Consider a variable that has a risk ratio of 2.  This ratio cannot apply to someone with a base risk $> \frac{1}{2}$.