# How to use R glm() to estimate risk ratios and ratio of risk ratios with confidence intervals

Tags: r, confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model, relative-risk

Given these data, reflecting individual data on 206 subjects, two treatment groups ("uc" and "texting") and race ("nonblack" and "black").

My goal is a calculate a risk ratio (with 95% CI) for each treatment group. The risk ratio of interest is defined as the proportion with outcome == 1 in the 'nonblack' category divided by the proportion with outcome == 1 in the 'black' category.  How do I calcuate these in R using a logistic (or Poisson model)?

```
agg_dat <- structure(list(trt_grp = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), levels = c("texting", "uc"), class = "factor"), race = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("black", "nonblack"), class = "factor"), 
    ascertained = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("yes", 
    "no"), class = "factor"), counts = c(21, 9, 24, 49, 32, 3, 
    63, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Converting to a row for each individual and setting factor levels:

```
dat <- uncount(agg_dat, counts) |> 
  mutate(outcome = ifelse(ascertained == "yes", 1, 0)) |> 
  mutate(race = factor(race, levels = c("black", "nonblack")),
  trt_grp = factor(trt_grp, levels = c("uc", "texting")))
```

It's straightforward to get predictions for each category of trt_grp and race:

```
    m0 <- glm(outcome ~ race*trt_grp, family = "binomial", data = dat)
    (newdata <-  agg_dat |> 
      select(trt_grp, race) |> 
      unique())
   predictions <- predict(m0, newdata, type = "response")
```

I'm stuck on how to use my R glm() model to estimate the confidence intervals for these risk ratios.

The point estimates for the risk ratios can be calculated from model predictions (on the "response" scale).

```
(rr_uc <- predicted[1]/predicted[2])
(rr_texting <- predicted[3]/predicted[4])
```

I wish to calculate 95% confidence intervals for 'rr_uc' and 'rr_texting'.  It seems like the R *margins* package might be useful.

Finally, I'd like to estimate the ratio of risk ratios, i.e., rr_texting/rr_uc. The point estimate is straightforward.  How do I calculate the confidence interval for the ratio of risk ratios?

Comment: You need something like the **delta method**.  Or you could fit a log-link Poisson model and get risk ratios directly from exponentiated parameters.  Or you could use something from the `effectsize` package to convert from CIs of odds ratios (which are available directly) to CIs of risk ratios. Or you could compute risk ratios directly from the 2x2 tables (again using `effectsize`)

Comment: You can try profile likelihood, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/289008/confidence-interval-on-binomial-effect-size/406746#406746

Comment: One recommended approach is to fit a Poisson glm: m1 <- glm(outcome = trt_grp*race, family = "poisson", data = dat)  then use the 'sandwich and 'lmtest' packages ti estimate robust confidence intervals, i.e., exp(coefci(m1, vcov. = vcovHC(m1, type = "HCO"))). The ratio of risk ratios is the exponentiated coefficient for the interaction, i.e., exp(coef[4]).  Estimates seem reasonable.  I have not yet sorted out how to get robust estimates for linear combinations of coefficients, i.e., rr_texting which is exp( coef[3] + coef[4] ).